# Salvar sem acentos e em maiúsculo SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou criando um banco de dados, onde preciso salvar todos os campos varchar em maiúsculo. Buscando na internet, encontrei o seguinte collate que funcionaria, mas ele ainda continua salvando com acentos e em maiúsculos e minúsculos. Segue o exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE Cidades(
  CodCidade int identity(1,1) not null,
  Descricao varchar(80) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CS_AS not null,
  CodEstado int not null,
  CodIBGE varchar(30) not null,
  Excluido bit not null default 0,
  CONSTRAINT PK_Cidades PRIMARY KEY(CodCidade)
)
```

Alguém sabe o que está errado para este collate não funcionar? Tem alguma outra?

Comment: Você quer realmente **salvar sem acentos e em upcase**? Não seria melhor salvar com tudo normal e apenas ignorá-los (acento e casing) na hora de fazer as consultas? Digo, não me parece uma boa ideia remover os acentos e o casing que o usuário escolheu, não acha? Se fosse pra fazer isso, acho que seria muito melhor tratar na camada de visualização para manter a entrada do usuário como upcase e ignorar os acentos...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O **collation** SQL não pode ajudar neste caso. Ele definirá, no máximo, que a acentuação e o *case* (maiúsculo/minúsculo) deve ser ignorado nas buscas.

Para fazer a conversão e de fato persistir tudo em maiúsculas, sem acento, você precisará converter o texto antes de persistir, usando alguma função específica para isso.

MS SQL Server não possui função nativa para remover acentuação. Você teria que criar esta função você mesmo em SQL, ou criar esta função na camada de aplicação caso você tenha uma (em C# ou Java, por exemplo).

## Algoritmo

Uma das maneiras de fazer é usando dois arrays para fazer um **"de-para"**, daí você percorre a palavra, caractere a caractere, busca a posição do caractere original no primeiro array e obtém o caractere substituto no segundo array, nesta mesma posição.

Tendo apenas os caracteres acentuados e seus substitutos nos arrays, caso um caractere não seja encontrado, basta retornar ele mesmo.

Além das substituições de caracteres acentuados por não acentuados, você também deve converter tudo para *upper case* (para isto as linguagens já incluem função nativa, inclusive o SQL Server).

## Funções prontas da linguagem

Eventualmente a linguagem que você usa já possui algumas funções prontas para ajudar com parte do trabalho.

Por exemplo, o C# possui o `String.Normalize` que já ajuda bastante. Veja [este exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249087/how-do-i-remove-diacritics-accents-from-a-string-in-net):

```c#
static string RemoveDiacritics(string text) 
{
    var normalizedString = text.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var c in normalizedString)
    {
        var unicodeCategory = CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c);
        if (unicodeCategory != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
        {
            stringBuilder.Append(c);
        }
    }

    return stringBuilder.ToString().Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC);
}
```

O código acima primeiro separa as letras de seus acentos ou cedilha usando o *String.Normalize*, e depois percorre o resultado removendo os caracteres de acentuação que foram separados das letras, deixando apenas as letras.

Ao resultado desta função acima você ainda precisa aplicar o `string.UpperCase()`. Mais ou menos assim:

```c#
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var textoOriginal = "É é ç";
    var textoConvertido = RemoveDiacritics(textoOriginal).ToUpper();

    Console.WriteLine(textoConvertido);
}
```

A saída do código acima é `E E C`.

Comment: Ta ok, muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 3):

**Solução 1:**

Combine *collation* com função `UPPER` ao adicionar registros na coluna.

```
INSERT INTO Cidades(Descricao, CodEstado, CodIBGE)
    values(UPPER('São Paulo'), 1, 1)

output:
CodCidade   Descricao   CodEstado   CodIBGE Excluido
1           SAO PAULO   1           1       0
```

A sua *collation* já deveria remover os acentos, mas usando `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI` também funciona.

Para pesquisar outras *collations* rode:

```
select name, COLLATIONPROPERTY(name, 'CodePage') as Code_Page, description
from   sys.fn_HelpCollations()
```

**Solução 2:**

Crie um campo a parte, como `DescricaoNormalizada`, para não perder o valor original:

```
Descricao varchar(80) not null,
DescricaoNormalizada varchar(80) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CS_AS null,
```

preechendo com o valor normalizado através de *triggers* (gatilhos) ou explicitamente no INSERT, resultando em:

```
CodCidade   Descricao   DescricaoNormalizada    CodEstado   CodIBGE Excluido
1           São Paulo   SAO PAULO               1           1       0
```

**Solução 3:**

Não faça nada no banco de dados, deixe a transformação a cargo do backend, ou frontend caso o objetivo seja formatação.

```
Descricao varchar(80) not null,
```